# Count Month on between 2 date

Tags: php, datetime

I know is silly question, but i need u help guys.

Theres something weird if i use datediff,

example

```
$begin = "2016-01-01"; $end = "2016-01-31";
$date1=date_create(date_format($begin,"Y-m-d"));
$date2=date_create(date_format($end,"Y-m-d"));

$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2); $month = $diff->format("%m");
```

when i echo $month is show `0`. It should be `1`, because Last Day of January is `31` Days. But why does it is show `0`?

If i change `$end = "2016-02-01";`

is becomes `1`. Can u help me this??

Comment: It's not 1 month. It's 30 days.

Comment: there should a method called `TimeSpan`

Comment: @Rihard - So the solutio is?? 
@ Arjit - so how to use that?</br>
i'm really stuck :(

Comment: Add another check if the dates are 1st & last date of a month.

Comment: @Wolfzat `date_diff()` is returning the correct solution. `$month = 0`, because there are only 30 days between January 1st and January 31st, which is less than a month.

Comment: since jan have 31 days so the code  is showing correct result. Better to show year month and days all in the end of result. that will be more clear

Answer (score 1):

It's returning the correct answer as there is a difference of 30 days only so a month has not passed yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$timeStart = strtotime("2016-01-01");
$timeEnd = strtotime("2016-01-31");
// Adding current month + all months in each passed year
$months = 1 + (date("Y",$timeEnd)-date("Y",$timeStart))*12;
// Add/subtract month difference
$months += date("m",$timeEnd)-date("m",$timeStart);

echo $months; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
<?php 
$begin = "2016-01-01"; $end = "2016-01-31";
$date1=new DateTime($begin);
$date2=new DateTime($end);
$date2->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$diff=$date2->diff($date1); 
$month = $diff->m;
print_r($month);
?>
```

Comment: well i try it myself and it's work, u just $diff->m; It's working lol. Tq for helping